# Cache one large object and read from cache fast for flask

Tags: python, caching, memcached, flask

I tried `flask-cache` to cache an object(about 800MB) like this:

```
@cache.memoize(50000)
def get_nmf_result():
    return NMF_Recommendation(basis_path = app.config['BASIS_PATH'],
                              coef_path = app.config['COEF_PATH'],
                              mask_path = app.config['MASK_PATH'])
```

But I found that (1) It takes quite a long time to do the caching

(2) Even I cached it, it still need quite a while to read from the cache. Does that mean when I read the cache, actually I'm getting a `copy`instead of `reference` of the cache?

Does anyone have ideas about quick storing and reading for cache? Thanks!

Comment: Which cache backend are you using? The ones that store data in memory are faster, but in your case they'd consume a lot of memory. Do you really need to cache such big amounts of data?

Answer (score 4):

Flask-Cache uses the Werkzeug cache, which uses the pickling library to serialize any cache values to a binary blob, so the value can be saved in any backend. Pickling and unpickling a 800MB object could take quite some time, especially if it's not just one big string or something "simple" like that.

At this point, i think it's better to write your own cache, tailored to the backend you use and the type of data you store.